# How to change variable values when a target is called

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have following things in my Makefile(GNU)

```
DLIB =  $(DLIB_STATIC)
DLIBFLAGS = $(DLIB_STATIC)
DLIB_BUILDS =  $(DLIB_STATIC) LIBDDUMMY

# DLIB =  $(DLIB_SHARED)
# DLIBFLAGS = -Llib -lD
# DLIB_BUILDS =  $(DLIB_SHARED)

all: BUILDALL TB
tgt2: BUILDALL TB

TB: $(DLIB_BUILDS)
```

I need to modify values of `DLIB, DLIBFLAGS & DLIB_BUILDS` as follows

```
DLIB =  $(DLIB_SHARED)
DLIBFLAGS = -Llib -lD
DLIB_BUILDS =  $(DLIB_SHARED)
```

when `tgt2` is called.

I tried following

```
TEMP:
  DLIB =  $(DLIB_SHARED)
  DLIBFLAGS = -Llib -lD
  DLIB_BUILDS =  $(DLIB_SHARED)

tgt2: TEMP BUILDALL
```

But it not working, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

GNU make has notion about [target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html). Just place variable's assignment in place of target's prerequisites:

```
tgt2: DLIB = $(DLIB_SHARED)
tgt2: DLIBFLAGS = -Llib -lD
tgt2: DLIB_BUILDS = $(DLIB_SHARED)

tgt2: BUILDALL
```

That way, if `BUILDALL` target is built via `tgt2`, it will use special set of variable's values.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me, if `BUILDALL` target has just `echo $(DLIB)` receipt. How exactly your `BUILDALL` target uses given variables? Note, that if you have prerequisite files for `BUILDALL` target already built via `make all`, then calling `make tgt2` doesn't rebuild these files. You need to clear them first.